# Lua string.find can't find the last word in a line

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

It's a case in the book programming in Lua. The code is followed, my question is why it can't get the last word of the line?

```
function allwords()
   local line=io.read()
   local pos=1
   return function ()
      while line do
         local s,e=string.find(line,"%w+ ",pos)
         if s then
            pos=e+1
            return string.sub(line,s,e)   
         else
            line=io.read()
            pos=1
         end
      end
      return nil
   end
end

for word in allwords() do
   print(word)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
local s,e=string.find(line,"%w+ ",pos)
--                             ^
```

There is a whitespace in the pattern `"%w+ "`, so it matches a word followed by a whitespace. When you input, e.g, `word1 word2 word3` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `word3` has no whitespace following it.

There is no whitespace in the example of the book:

```
local s, e = string.find(line, "%w+", pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for, uh, "resurrecting" this question, but I think I have a better solution.

Instead of using your *allwords* function, could you not just do this:

```
for word in io.read():gmatch("%S+") do
   print(word)
end
```

The function

```
gmatch("%S+")
```

returns all the words in a string.